# Why does iron(III) form the trithiocyanate complex instead of the triisothiocyanate one?

Tags: hsab

[image]

As far as I know, $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ is a hard acid, and thus shouldn't it favor complexation with the nitrogen's lone pair rather than the softer S?

Comment: How hard is the nitrogen?  Doesn't pi bonding have something to do with hardness/softness?