# Why does thiocyanate bind to Fe³⁺ with the S side instead of the N side?

Tags: coordination-compounds, hsab

According to hard and soft acids and bases (HSAB) theory, "soft" Lewis bases bind to "soft" Lewis acids, and "hard" Lewis bases bind to "hard" Lewis acids.

$\ce{Fe^3+}$ is a hard Lewis acid. In $\ce{SCN-}$, either the $\ce{N}$ or the $\ce{S}$ side of the molecule can bind with $\ce{Fe^3+}$. Of the two, $\ce{N}$ is the harder Lewis base. But $\ce{[Fe(SCN)6]^3-}$ has a $\ce{Fe-S}$ bond and not a $\ce{Fe-N}$ bond. Why is this so?

Comment: Already asked https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/93792/why-does-ironiii-form-the-trithiocyanate-complex-instead-of-the-triisothiocyan